# How to access item in nested hashmap without multiple clones?

Tags: rust, nested-map

There is a `TokenBalances` struct defined using a nested map. I want to implement a the `balance_of` method which takes two keys: token, account as input, and returns the balance as output.

```
use std::collections::*;

type TokenId = u128;
type AccountId = u128;
type AccountBalance = u128;

#[derive(Default, Clone)]
struct TokenBalances {
    balances: HashMap<TokenId, HashMap<AccountId, AccountBalance>>,
}

impl TokenBalances {
    fn balance_of(&self, token: TokenId, account: AccountId) -> AccountBalance {
        self.balances
            .get(&token)
            .cloned()
            .unwrap_or_default()
            .get(&account)
            .cloned()
            .unwrap_or_default()
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", TokenBalances::default().balance_of(0, 0)) // 0
}
```

It uses `cloned` twice to turn an `Option<&T>` to `Option<T>`

I'm aware of `to_owned` as an alternative to `cloned`, but in its docs it says

> Creates owned data from borrowed data, usually by cloning.

I'm wondering if the clones are really necessary. Is there any idomatic way to rewrite the method without cloning twice? And are clones completely avoidable?

Comment: Why is read-only references to the data bad?  Why are you cloning at all?

Comment: @KevinAnderson clone is used to turn Option<&T> returned by `get()` to Option<T> for convenience

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Option::and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then):

```
self.balances
    .get(&token)
    .and_then(|map| map.get(&account))
    .copied()
    .unwrap_or_default()
```

The `and_then` call returns an `Option<&AccountBalance>`. This is then cloned/copied with `copied`. This is fine as it's just a `u128` right now. If it ever becomes a more complex type where copying isn't cheap, make `balance_of` return `&AccountBalance` instead. Then you can remove the `copied()` call and `unwrap_or(&0)` for example.

Last note: the `unwrap_or_default` might hint at a code smell. I don't know your context, but it might make more sense to actually return `Option<AccountBalance>` from the method instead of defaulting to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Your need to clone comes from the fact that you are using `unwrap_or_default` inbetween. Without the clone, you have an `Option<&HashMap>` (as per `HashMap::get` on the outer map) and `&HashMap` does not implement `Default` - where should this default reference point to? Luckily, we don't actually need an owned `HashMap`, the reference to the inner map totally suffices to do a lookup. To chain two functions that may return `None`, one uses `Option::and_then`. It is like `Option::map`, but flattens an `Option<Option<T>>` into just an `Option<T>`. In your case, the code would look like this:

```rust
impl TokenBalances {
    fn balance_of(&self, token: TokenId, account: AccountId) -> AccountBalance {
        self.balances
            .get(&token)
            .and_then(|inner_map| inner_map.get(&account))
            .copied()
            .unwrap_or_default()
    }
}
```

I also changed the final `cloned` to `copied`, which indicates that this clone is cheap.